# How to get achieve form style in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am Trying to achieve below style using bootstrap framework. I was able to achieve some what similar to this,  but the problem is the save button is not getting aligned to right(not taking available width). There is a gap between save button and red border wrapper. Is there any way to to get the button take available width? or is it possible using `inline-form` or something? please help.

[image]

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div style="border:1px solid red;" class="container mb-4">
  <div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col-5">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="sel-city" class="col-form-label col-md-2">Label</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <select class="form-control custom-select" id="sel-city" name="city"></select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="sel-zone" class="col-form-label col-md-2">Label</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <select class="form-control custom-select" id="sel-zone" name="workzone"></select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="sel-stage" class="col-form-label col-md-2">label</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <select class="form-control custom-select" id="sel-stage" name="stage">
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="sel-status" class="col-form-label col-md-2">Label</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <select class="form-control custom-select" id="sel-status" name="status"></select>
        </div>
        <button id="btn-status-save" class="btn btn-primary float-right" onclick="saveStatus()">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have a `container` anywhere. If you add that class to the `div` with the red border, it might clear things up.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have added the class to the div but there is still space after the button. I need the button to take full-width in that space.

Comment: Sounds like a good time to start [looking at the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/). I'm sure there's a class in there that causes an item to be pulled right...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for the suggestion, but the float didn't worked :(

Comment: I think you need more divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I restructured your html a bit so it flows automatically (see example)

Key things to note directly related to your question:

For the button (classes)
btn-block: This will make the button expand the entire available width of the container div.

For the column (classes):
align-self-end : will put item at the very bottom right of div; would need to add mb-3 to add bottom margin so it aligns with your other element.

noPadding: custom css class. By default, cols will have padding on the left and right side. You will want to override this with a css class if you want to kill that off.

```css
.noPadding {
 padding-right: 0px !important;
 padding-left: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div style="border:1px solid red;" class="container mb-4">
  <div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sel-city" class="col-form-label col-md-2">Label</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <select class="form-control custom-select" id="sel-city" name="city"></select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sel-zone" class="col-form-label col-md-2">Label</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <select class="form-control custom-select" id="sel-zone" name="workzone"></select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sel-stage" class="col-form-label col-md-2">label</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <select class="form-control custom-select" id="sel-stage" name="stage">
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="sel-status" class="col-form-label col-md-2">Label</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <select class="form-control custom-select" id="sel-status" name="status"></select>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col align-self-end mb-3 noPadding">
            <button id="btn-status-save" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"  onclick="saveStatus()">Save</button>
    </div>

  </div>

  </div>
```